# Create a BigQuery table based on date

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to automate creating a new table in BigQuery based on the date like
mytable_20210304, mytable_20210303, mytable_20210302, ...

I've tried declaring a table variable name like

```
DECLARE mytable STRING DEFAULT CONCAT("mytable", CURRENT_DATE())
```

and then creating the table like `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mytable`

but I'm getting the error message

```
"Table name missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request"
```

The tables that I'm querying also depends on the date and when I try just creating a hardcoded table name like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE `mytable`
```

it works fine. Is there something I'm missing? Is this functionality possible?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your table name should be prefixed by a dataset name, e.g., `CREATE TABLE yourdataset.yourTable;`
2. to create a table with dynamic name, you will need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate))

```
DECLARE mytable STRING DEFAULT CONCAT("mytable", CURRENT_DATE());
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE mydataset.' || mytable || '(x INT64)';
```